# Magento 1.8 - Very strange issues with redirects caused by our hosts tech support team

Tags: magento-1.8, php, htaccess, .htaccess, 301-redirect

We asked our hosts tech support to change the 302 redirects to 301's...after numerous attempts by them i gave up on them and accepted that they could not do it.

Now they have left us where none of the sidebar menus on our homepage work because they link to a page which looks like the correct one but has no functioning price drop downs & the url is wrong in the browser bar. (The correct page still works if typed into the browser bar so it still exists.)

When most links are clicked, the page fades out and a blue loading icon appears which is dramatically slowing the load time down. This does not happen when you click the " about us" link for some reason.

We have cleared cookies, tried different pcs, cleared the CDN cache & empited the var/sessions and var/cache folders but nothing has fixed the issue.

If you visit the homepage and click the "home" button, the side menu works but the homepage has no banner slider so to me it seems it is a different version of the website...

This has been through about 10 technical gurus and they have not been able to fix it at all.

Does anyone have any idea what siteground have done to my website or how to fix it? I have tried restoring the .htaccess file that was in place previously but this has not fixed the issue so basically my website is broken.

Comment: This doesn't seem like something that can happen just with a .htaccess tweak. What else did they do? Did you do anything else as well?

Comment: I've no idea how it happened. IT was a very odd situation. Luckily I did a restore on the database & this corrected the issues. It is amazing how a tiny issue can become a big one.

Comment: I guess they touched more than just a .htaccess redirection. Anyway happy to hear that it's corrected now. :)